# Can we float 2 divs side by side and 3rd one below them?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I want to arrange 3 divs, according to the screen width as follows:

For `screen-width of < 500px` arrangement should be as follows :

[image: layout < 500px]

For `screen-width of > 500px` arrangement should be as follows :

[image: layout > 500px]

I have tried achieving this in screen size of > 500px but i don't know how to use the same code to achieve arrangement for <500px.

My doubt is, can I use the same piece of code to get both the arrangements or is there any other approach ? Can flexbox be used to solve the issue?

Here is the snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.divA {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="divA">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="divB">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="divC">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you removed the container 2 div it would be possible

Comment: @Pete it's working fine for >500px arrangement , what should be done to get <500px arrangement ?

Answer (score 2):

**edit**

**after seeing your question  update** , mediaquerie, `flex`, `order` , and a pseudo to create that empty gap , should be enough. Still with each 3 boxes direct child of `.container`.

run the code snippet in fullpage mode and resize your browser , break point set at 700px for the demo.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.divA {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.divB {
  background: lightblue;
}

.divC {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.container>div,
.container:before {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 40%;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  /* upadte here the px value where you swhitch to happen . 500px */
  .divA,
  .divC {
    order: 1;
    flex: 0 1 40%;
  }
  .container .divB,
  .container .divC {
    flex: 0 1 60%;
  }
  .container:before {
    content: "";
    flex: 0 1 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="divA">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="divC">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*original answer left here for infos*

you may switch from a flex layout to a table or grid layout with each elelemnts as sibblings, no need of extra markup here.

exemple : flex/table , *it would be for browser still having issues with grid*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
  border: solid;
  min-width: 40%;
}


/* set here the width where you want switching layout */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    ;
  }
  .divA {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="divA">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="divC">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

or grid (*mind version of IE which supports grid partially and requires to set grid-row/grid-column or grid-area for each children*)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.container>div {
  border: solid;
}

.divC {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column:1 / span 2;
}


/* set here the width where you want switching layout */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .divC {
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="divA">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="divC">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### How:

This can be achieved with css [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

If you are open to grid solution, You need to change your html structure a bit. With `flex` that's impossible.

### Solution:

Here is what I would do:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.divA {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.divB {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.divC {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .divA {
    grid-column: 2 / 1;
    grid-row: 2 / 2

  }
  .divB {
    grid-column: 2 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
  }
  .divC {
    grid-column: 2 / 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="divA">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="divC">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

### Explanation:

- `grid-template-columns` lets you define the column widths of your
  grid elements, and same does the `grid-template-rows` for rows
  heights.
- For each grid element, you can specify how many elements they should
  span ( such as table cell can span columns or rows ) with
  `grid-column`. Learn more
  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-column.asp) or google
  this property. Your `divC` has spanned 2 elements in a column.
- Now for your responsiveness, write a media query to define your
  styles for `screen-width` more than `500px`, and reset your `.divC`s
  `grid-column` and `grid-row` and add the same for your `.divA`. (Since this element now spans 2 elements in a row)

Comment: can you check the updated image uploaded ( for >500px) and tell me if it can be done using grid layout?

Comment: answer updated, accept if it fulfils your requirement now :)